# How to disable a option in dropdown by ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How can we disable the second value punchout by ngOnInit?
 `<form [formGroup]="articleForm" (ngSubmit)="onArticleFormSubmit()">`

```
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Select list: </label>
          <select name="leave" class="form-control" formControlName="list_type" >
            <option value="punchIn"  >
     PunchIn
   </option>
            <option value="punchOut" >
  PunchOut
   </option>
 </select>   
  </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: `<option value="punchOut" disabled>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component,

```
disabled:boolean;
 ngOnInit() {

           this.disabled=true;
        }
```

In your html,

```
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Select list: </label>
          <select name="leave" class="form-control" formControlName="list_type" >
            <option value="punchIn"  >
     PunchIn
   </option>
            <option value="punchOut" [disabled]="disabled" >
  PunchOut
   </option>
 </select>   
  </div>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select name="leave" class="form-control" formControlName="list_type" >
  <option value="punchIn"> PunchIn </option>
  <option value="punchOut" [disabled]="true" > PunchOut </option>
</select>
```